# Como ler uma tabela faltando elementos ou mal configurada?

Tags: r, data.frame, read.table

Suponha uma tabela em forma de texto como a seguinte:

```
texto <- "a b c
e f
g h i"
```

Quando uso o comando read.table, dá o seguinte erro:

```
tabela <- read.table(text=texto)
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 2 did not have 3 elements
```

Como contornar este problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma forma de resolver o problema é colocando o argumento `fill=TRUE` no `read.table`:

```
tabela <- read.table(text=texto, fill=TRUE)
tabela
 V1 V2 V3
1  a  b  c
2  e  f   
3  g  h  i
```